# How to add UIWebView to a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I am new to development in **Objective-C**, I am trying to create a table view, and making each cell contains a web view.
I want to load some paragraphs from database, and put each one in a div that exist a web view, and each web view should be in a cell in the **UITableView**.
Can you help me kindly?

Comment: dont do like this if all data comes from the database then create your owen structure for that like div = redBG and line=graycolor etc

Comment: Pay attention with UIWebview cause it takes a lot of memory

Comment: Just create webview in the UITableViewCell and you just load the link in CellForRowAtIndex:

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add UIWebView on UITableViewCell just like you did with UIView. Better way is to create custom table view cell which contain UIWebView and you can load html on webview when cell delegate calls

use below code:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><div>%@</div></body></html>",Paragraph] baseURL:nil];
```